# Column calculation comparison in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to commit a query that would return a value if a calculation turns out TRUE and FALSE if FALSE.

```
SELECT 
IF(VALID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,"NULL") AS NAME,
IF(SALARY/DAYS > 1000, TRUE, FALSE) AS VALID;
```

Seems like the VALID var is unknown to MYSQL until the query is over.
So my question is:
Is there any possible way to evaluate **VALID** for that query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT IF(VALID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,"NULL") AS NAME, VALID
from (select t.*, IF(SALARY/DAYS > 1000, TRUE, FALSE) AS VALID
      from t
     ) t
```

I'm not a big fan of replicating logic.  I much prefer to use subqueries to define variables.  This makes it much easier to change the definitions.  In general, this doesn't affect performance, because (most) sql engines are smart enough to do the calculations with one read through the data.

Answer (score 1):

No. Aliases can't be used like that in the same query.

You'll have to repeat yourself.

```
SELECT 
IF(SALARY/DAYS > 1000,EMPLOYEE_NAME,"NULL") AS NAME,
IF(SALARY/DAYS > 1000, TRUE, FALSE) AS VALID;
```

Comment: SALARY/DAYS is a very long and complex expression. Is there a way to kind of define it in the beginning of the query and just reference it later, pretty much like we do in code ? As in $var = expression(..); if ($var) do ... ; if ($var) do ...;  ?

Comment: @Ted well you have a few ways : subquery, view, stored procedure... hard to say what would be the best if you just give "sample" code !